# select the text of wpf textbox on click

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have implemented mentioned code to select the text of WPF textbox but it doesn't work.
 the event which fires is the "PreviewMouseDown"

```
txtQuantity.SelectionStart = 0
txtQuantity.SelectionLength = txtQuantity.Text.Length
```

Comment: Length - 1;  also you've tagged this C# but that's VB.Net, please don't do that.

Comment: You can just use [AutoSelectTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AutoSelectTextBox&referringTitle=Home) from [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It works on `PreviewMouseUp`.

Comment: Thanks #wickramaranga...it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to select the text of a textbox, with a click on the textbox itself, this will work.

Event `PreviewMouseUp`,

Code:

```
txtQuantity.SelectAll()
```

or,

```
txtQuantity.Select(start, length)
```

The event `PreviewMouseDown` doesn't work because, the effect done by mouse down is overruled by the event `PreviewMouseUp` which makes the real "Click". Try holding the mouse button to see this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PreviewMouseDown Event for that
Use GotFocus() or MouseUp Event and in that event write following line

```
textBox1.SelectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use PreviewMouseUp event. because when you select textbox`s text after another process deselect textbox`s text. The deselected textbox`s text event work between mouse down and mouse up  events

```
    private void textBox_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();

    }
```